# Exception in GraalVM 22.2 native-image on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: graalvm

I am trying to compile a Java app into a native image using GraalVM 22.2 on my Ubuntu 22.04 workstation.  I have followed the installation instructions here:

https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/docs/getting-started/linux/

GraalVM is installed and seems happy:

```
# /opt/graalvm/bin/java -version
openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.2.0 (build 17.0.4+8-jvmci-22.2-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.2.0 (build 17.0.4+8-jvmci-22.2-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here's how I'm calling native-image for my app:

```
/opt/graalvm/bin/native-image \
  -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=graalvm/reflect.json \
  -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
  --no-fallback \
  --enable-url-protocols=http \
  --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory \
  --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger \
  --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder \
  -jar ../app/target/app-0.9.jar
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
Error: Collecting native-compiler info with '/usr/bin/gcc -v' failed
Error: To prevent native-toolchain checking provide command-line option -H:-CheckToolchain
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Collecting native-compiler info with '/usr/bin/gcc -v' failed
To prevent native-toolchain checking provide command-line option -H:-CheckToolchain
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:138)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.addSkipCheckingInfo(CCompilerInvoker.java:104)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.<init>(CCompilerInvoker.java:72)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker$LinuxCCompilerInvoker.<init>(CCompilerInvoker.java:212)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.create(CCompilerInvoker.java:80)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:891)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:561)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:521)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
```

However, gcc is installed and is also happy:

```
# /usr/bin/gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-gBFGDP/gcc-11-11.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-gBFGDP/gcc-11-11.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
```

Comment: There's an option, `-H:+TraceNativeToolUsage`, that might help investigating compiler/linker related problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that some permissions got clobbered in the /opt/graalvm folder.  Removing and re-extracting the folder fixed the problem for me.